# How many vertices can a convex polytope have?

Tags: convex-polytopes

One has an $n$-dimensional convex polytope $P$ represented by an intersection of half-spaces:

\begin{equation}H_i = \{ (x_1,x_2, \ldots,x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid \sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij} x_j \ge a_{i0}, \ a_{ij} \in \mathbb{R} \}, \ i = \overline{1,k} \end{equation}
\begin{equation}P = \{ X \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid X \in \bigcap_{i=1}^k H_i \} \end{equation}

Then let's say that $(v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_n) \in P$ is a vertex if we can find at least $n$ subspaces (out of $k$) such that 
\begin{equation}\sum_{j=1}^n a_{\tilde i j} v_j = a_{\tilde i 0}, \quad \text{ for some } \tilde i \in \{ 1,2, \ldots , k\} 
\end{equation}

Now let's get to the point. It is known that we must have at least $k = n+1$ subspaces in order to construct a closed convex polytope. In this initial case it'd be a [simplex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex) having $n+1=|V|$ vertices (here $V$ is a set of vertices).

We can obviously introduce any number of somewhat trivial additional subspaces and stay at $|V|=n+1$ vertices, but **I am interested in the maximum number of vertices for any given number of subspaces** $k>n$ in $n$-dimensional space.

---

$\mathbb{R}^2$ case: since restrictions are geometrically half-planes one can draw lines on paper and see what happens. The simplest closed figure is a triangle, it has 3 vertices and needs a minimum of 3 restrictions to exist. Now every additional restriction can add no more than 1 additional vertice (this is obvious in 2-dimensional space). This means that *for $k \ge 3$ restrictions there can exist no more than $k$ vertices:* $\max |V| = k.$

$\mathbb{R}^3$ case: similarly the simplest closed figure is a triangular pyramid, it has 4 vertices and needs a minimum of 4 restrictions to exist. Now it gets a little more complicated with additional restrictions, but what follows from [fiddling with Euler characteristic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyhedral_combinatorics#Equalities_and_inequalities) is that *for $k \ge 4$ restrictions there can exist no more than $(2k-4)$ vertices:* $\max |V| = 2k-4.$

$\mathbb{R}^n$ case: I only understand clearly that $\max_{k = n+1} |V| = n+1.$ What happens after introducing additional restrictions is hard to conceive.

How can I generalize it? I hoped to draw some conclusions from [Dehn–Sommerville equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dehn%E2%80%93Sommerville_equations) but I am not quite experienced enough and maybe it's a completely wrong way to look at this problem...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Using $k$ half-spaces, the polytope has at most $k$ facets. For a fixed number of facets, the number of vertices is maximized, for example, by the [dual polytope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_polytope) of the [cyclic polytope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_polytope) with $k$ vertices. More generally, by the dual polytope of any [neighborly polytope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neighborly_polytope) with $k$ vertices.
This maximum number of vertices is equal to
$${k-\lceil n/2 \rceil \choose \lfloor n/2 \rfloor} + {k-\lfloor n/2 \rfloor - 1 \choose \lceil n/2 \rceil - 1}.$$

Comment: Jan, Do you have a source or proof for the equation you provided on April 12, 2013 which provides the maximum number of vertices given a particular number of half-spaces (k) and a particular ambient dimension (n)? Thank you!

Comment: See for example the Wikipedia page on the "upper bound theorem": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upper_bound_theorem

Comment: See, for example, Theorem 5.4.5 in Lectures on Discrete Geometry by Jiří Matoušek (https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4613-0039-7)

Answer (score 13):

What you call $n$ in your posting is often called $d$ in the literature, but I will stick with
your notation.  So $n$ is the dimension.  Let $V$ be the number of vertices, and $k$ the number
of facets.
Then $V = \Theta( k ^ {\lfloor n/2 \rfloor} )$.
More precisely, the maximum $V$ is given by McMullen's *Upper Bound Theorem*,
realized by duals of [cyclic polytopes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_polytope). Cyclic polytopes maximize the number
of facets for a fixed number of vertices, so their duals maximize the number of vertices
for a fixed number of facets.

    
[image: CyclicPolytope]

See, e.g.,

> "Basic Properties Of Convex Polytopes."
> Martin Henk, Jürgen Richter-Gebert, and Günter M. Ziegler.
> *[Handbook of Discrete and Computational Geometry](https://www.crcpress.com/Handbook-of-Discrete-and-Computational-Geometry-Third-Edition/Toth-ORourke-Goodman/p/book/9781498711395)*, Chapter 16. CRC Press. 2004.
> Now Chapter 15 in the *Handbook* [3rd edition](https://www.routledge.com/Handbook-of-Discrete-and-Computational-Geometry-Third-Edition/Toth-ORourke-Goodman/p/book/9781498711395).

Comment: I see that now that the answer Jan posted as I was preparing mine are essentially the same.

Comment: Is there a direct way of finding vertex sets $V_d$ without calculating the dual ? Thanks

Comment: @denis: That is called [vertex enumeration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_enumeration_problem) in the literature. The Avis-Fukuda algorithm is now standard.

Comment: Actually I want the H-form -- $A, b$ for which $Ax \leq b, x \geq 0$ is difficult to solve: many vertices but not necessarily cyclic polytope. Thanks anyway.

Comment: You give here a $\Theta$ expression $n^{d/2}$ -- what would be the $O(n^{d/2})$ constant? Thanks.

Comment: @kloop: I don't know what is the best constant.