# Section of an $n$-dimensional convex polytope by $2$-dimensional plane

Tags: co.combinatorics, discrete-geometry, convex-polytopes

Consider an $n$-dimensional convex polytope with $k$ vertices. In the worst case the number of faces is exponential in $n$ and $k$.  Consider a $2$-dimensional plane which intersects this polytope, i.e., it intersects only a subset of all faces.  Can I bound the number of such intersected faces?  In the worst case, will this number be a polynomial in $n$ and $k$ or still exponential?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: by face you mean a face of codimension 1?

Comment: Yes, of dimension n-1

Comment: Also, you mean bound via $k$ for fixed $n$ or for $n$ varying with $k$? In the first case it is not true that the number of faces may be exponential.

Comment: n is fixed. Why? Is there some formula for this kind of bounds? Or maybe an example of such polytope?

Comment: When $n$ is fixed, any face of dimension $n-1$ lies in a span of certain $n$ vertices, thus there are at most $\binom{k}n$ faces, this is polynomial in $n$. I guess that this bound is not sharp.

Comment: And if $n$ is varing with $k$?

Comment: For $n=2$ there are less than $2k$ faces. If you put a short pentagonal pyramid on each face of a dodecahedron you have $k=32$ and $60$ faces. That is probably the closest to $2$ that the ratio gets.

Comment: For the purposes of visualization, it may be easier to consider the dual question. I haven't thought about this in detail, but perhaps it is this one: for an $n$-polytope with $k$ facets, what is the maximal number of vertices that a $2$-dimensional projection can have?

Comment: Also, the maximal number of facets for given $n$ and $k$ has a well-known answer, see e.g. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/127423/how-many-vertices-can-a-convex-polytope-have (Again in the dual formulation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a paper wich shows that in the worst case it still can be exponential:
"Shadows and slices of polytopes, Nina Amenta et al., 1996"
https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=237228