# Upper bound on number of vertices in intersection (and union) of simplices

Tags: convex-polytopes, convex-geometry, convex-analysis

Let $S_1, \dots, S_k \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a set of (non-regular) simplices.  Let $m_i$ indicate the number of vertices of simplex $S_i$ (we do not assume it is equal to $n-1$).

Is there a simple upper bound on the maximum number of vertices of the intersection  $\bigcap_i S_i$, stated in terms of the set $\{ m_i\}_{i=1..k}$?

What about the maximum number of vertices of the convex hull of the union, $\mathrm{Conv}\big(\bigcup_i S_i\big)$?

(Cross-posting from [math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3210365/upper-bound-on-number-of-vertices-in-intersection-and-union-of-complex-polytopes))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the literature, the dimension is usually $d$ (rather than your $n$),
and the number objects is $n$ (rather than your $k$).

The intersection of $n$ halfspaces in dimension $d$ can have 
$n^{\lfloor d/2 \rfloor}$ vertices.
This is achieved by the dual of cyclic polytopes.
See the MO question 
[How many vertices can a convex polytope have?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/127423/6094).

For the union, although the union itself can be complicated, the
convex hull of the union is not: All the vertices of the simplices
could fall on the hull. So the union can have at
most $O(n d)$ vertices, because each of the $n$ simplices
can have at most $d+1$ vertices.

Comment: what is this complexity? The intersection of $n$ tetrahedra in $\mathbb{R}^3$ has $O(n)$ faces, thus $O(n)$ vertices.

Comment: In the plane, the union of $n/2$ thin horizontal triangles with $n/2$ thin vertical triangles produces a grid-like object with $\Omega(n^2)$ vertices. Perhaps we are using the word "vertices" differently?

Comment: we talk about different things: you about union, me about intersection)

Comment: $S_i$ are simplices, their intersection is convex, right?

Comment: @FedorPetrov: Apologies for misunderstaning you, and for not noticing that the OP asked for the complexity of the *hull* of the union.

Comment: Thanks grealy. The last point uses that any vertex of the convex of the hull of the union must be a vertex of one of the simplices, is that correct?

Comment: @Artemy: Yes, a created vertex of the union cannot appear on the hull. Only the original simplex vertices can appear on the hull.