# Polytope with most faces

Tags: discrete-geometry, convex-polytopes, convex-hulls

Fix $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$ with $m \ge n+1$. Take $m$ points in general position in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and let $P$ be their convex hull. What is the maximal number of (external, codimension-one) faces that $P$ can have, in terms of $m$ and $n$?

<sub>(Apologies if this is a well-known quantity.)</sub>

Comment: dual question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/127423/how-many-vertices-can-a-convex-polytope-have/

Comment: See the answers at Jan's link. "Cyclic polytopes maximize the number of facets for a fixed number of vertices." For you, $m$ is the number of vertices.

Comment: Thank you both! This is extremely helpful, particularly the closed form.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The upper bound conjecture of Motzkin, made a theorem by McMullen in 1970, states that the highest number of facets among all polytopes with $m$ vertices in $\mathbb R^n$ is the number of facets of the cyclic polytope $\Delta(m,n)$.